# Assigning a role from edit a specific category-tree of catalog

Tags: catalog, category-tree, permissions, role

I need to assign a role to edit a specific separate category in the catalog. I was hoping that "Roles Resources" have the opportunity to select from category-tree of the catalog. But didn't find such opportunities. How can it be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not allow this by default.
You can either allow admins to manage categories or not.
In the EE version you have the option to restrict access on a store view basis, but no category restriction.

What you can do is either include the category tree in the resources list when defining a role, but that seams kind of hard.

Or you can create a new section where you list the the category tree. [Here is an explanation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14842/146) on how you can add the category tree in your custom extension.

Then you rewrite the method `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController::_initCategory` and check if the current admin has access to that category.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by installing module - Advanced permission.