# Add category tree with checkboxes to the form

Tags: magento-1.6, category-tree

Is there any way to add a category tree with checkboxes to a form in the admin part?

The form contains two other fieldsets, and the category tree must be added as the third fieldset. All information that I have found was how to add a category tree separately, without injecting it in existing form. But here I need to render a block inside another block, or something like this.

I am curious how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will [find here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14842/146) and example about how to add the category tree in a separate tab.
You can start from there.
The block that renders the category tree behaves like any other block so it can be included anywhere.
All you have to do is to change the layout file and include that block in an other block and then display it using `getChildHtml`.
Or you can create a form element that uses a custom renderer and this renderer should be the block in question, but this is a little complicated.

Comment: Thanks! But `addTab` method is used there. I don't use it, I add tabs through xml declaration. Should I skip that step?

Comment: yes, you can skip that step

Comment: it seems, that quantities of subcategories are not displayed (in round brackets).

Comment: Maybe, you know how to enable display of those quantities, like this: http://prntscr.com/8yx9no?

Comment: it's kind of complicated. you need to add to the collection the product count and you need to change the method that displays the node. I don't remember how it's called.

Comment: Hello Marius. I am doing the same thing as in question. Can you explain the second method of renderer a little bit.? How can I do use it.?

Comment: @shashank You can find here an example on how you can add a custom attribute that uses a custom renderer: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/38445/146. It's for a different thing, but the idea is the same.

Comment: @shashank, for me it worked like that: `Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('your_block_name')->toHtml()`.

Comment: @Marius, finally, I found it - you only need to set `$this->_withProductCount` to `true` in constructor of a categories block.

Comment: I have posted my question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88929/add-category-tree-structure-in-custom-module-form