# Add category tree structure in custom module form

Tags: magento-1.9, module, adminform, category-tree

I want to have category tree structure in my custom module form as shown in below image-
[image]

i tried this link but no luck- 
[Add Category tree in custom extension](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14833/add-category-tree-in-custom-extension/14842#14842)

my module name is assel_po

here is my form.php

```
<?php

class Assel_Po_Block_Adminhtml_Poproduct_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {

  protected function _prepareForm() {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(
            array(
                'id' => 'edit_form',
                'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('po_product_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('po_product_id'))),
                'method' => 'post',
                'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
            )
        );

        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        $fieldset1 = $form->addFieldset('poproduct_form', array('legend' => Mage::helper('po')->__('Add Product')));
        $fieldset2 = $form->addFieldset('poproduct_detail_form', array('legend' => Mage::helper('po')->__("Product's More Details")));

        //var_dump(Mage::getSingleton('po/brands')->getAllbrands());

        if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getPoproductData()) 
        {
            $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getPoproductData();

            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getPoproductData(null);
        } 
        elseif (Mage::registry('poproduct_data')) 
        {
            $data = Mage::registry('poproduct_data')->getData();
        }


        /* Add fields in form */
        $po_id=$this->getRequest()->getParam('po_id');
        $data['po_id'] = $po_id;
        $fieldset1->addField('po_id', 'hidden', array(
            'name'      => 'po_id', 
            'value'      => $po_id,
        ));
    /*  
        $fieldset1->addField('new_exist', 'radios', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('po')->__('Choose any one'),
          'name'      => 'new_exist',
          'onclick' => "",
          'onchange' => "",
          'class'=>'new_exist',
          'value'  => '2',
          'values' => array(
                            array('value'=>'new','label'=>'Add New Product'),
                            array('value'=>'exist','label'=>'Update Existing Product'),
                       ),
          'disabled' => false,
          'readonly' => false,
          'tabindex' => 1
        ));
    */  

        $fieldset1->addField('product_id', 'text', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('po')->__('Product Id'),
                'class' => 'product-id',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'product_id',
                'disabled' => true,
                //'readonly'=> $data['product_id']==''?true:false,
        ));

        $fieldset1->addField('product_name', 'text', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('po')->__('Product Name'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'product_name',
        ));

        $fieldset1->addField('brand', 'select', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('po')->__('Brand'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'brand',
                'values'    => Mage::getSingleton('po/brands')->getAllbrands(),
        ));

        $fieldset1->addField('case', 'text', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('po')->__('Case'),
                'class' => '',
                'required' => false,
                'name' => 'case',
        ));

        $fieldset1->addField('upc', 'text', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('po')->__('UPC'),
                'class' => '',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'upc',
        ));

        $fieldset1->addField('billed_qty', 'text', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('po')->__('Billed Qty'),
                'class' => 'validate-digits',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'billed_qty',
        ));

        $fieldset1->addField('free_qty', 'text', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('po')->__('Free Qty'),
                'class' => 'validate-digits',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'free_qty',
                'value'  => '0',
        ));


    /*  
        $fieldset1->addField('qty', 'text', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('po')->__('Qty'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'qty',
        ));
    */

        $dateFormatIso = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);
        $fieldset1->addField('expiry_date', 'date', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('po')->__('Expiry Date'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'expiry_date',
                'image'  => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
                'input_format' => $dateFormatIso,
                'format'       => $dateFormatIso,
                'time' => true
        ));

        $fieldset1->addField('mrp', 'text', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('po')->__('MRP'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'mrp',
        ));

        $fieldset1->addField('rate', 'text', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('po')->__('Rate'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'rate',
        ));


        $fieldset1->addField('tax', 'select', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('po')->__('Tax(%)'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'tax',
                'values' => array(''=>'Select Tax','0' => 'Tax 0%','5' => 'Tax 5%', '14.5' => 'Tax 14.5')
        ));

        $fieldset1->addField('tax_amount', 'text', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('po')->__('Tax Amount'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'tax_amount',
        ));

        $fieldset1->addField('special_price', 'text', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('po')->__('Special Price'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'special_price',
        ));

        $fieldset1->addField('gross_amount', 'text', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('po')->__('Gross Amount'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'gross_amount',
        ));


        $fieldset1->addField('net_amount', 'text', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('po')->__('Net Amount'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'net_amount',
        ));

        $fieldset2->addField('category_ids', 'hidden', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('po')->__('Category'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => false,
                'name' => 'category_ids',
        ));

        $fieldset2->addField('label', 'label', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('po')->__('Category'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => false,
                'after_element_html' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('po/adminhtml_poproduct_edit_categories')->toHtml(),
        ));





        $form->setValues($data);

        return parent::_prepareForm();

  }

}
```

here is categories.php-

```
<?php
class Assel_Po_Block_Adminhtml_Poproduct_Edit_Categories extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tree {


    protected $_categoryIds = null;
    protected $_selectedNodes = null;
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('assel/po/categories.phtml');
        $this->_withProductCount = false;
    }

    public function getpoproduct(){
        return Mage::registry('current_poproduct'); //use other registration key if you have one
    }

    public function getCategoryIds(){
        if (is_null($this->_categoryIds)){
            $categories = $this->getpoproduct()->getSelectedCategories();
                $ids = array();
                foreach ($categories as $category){
                    $ids[] = $category->getId();
                }
                $this->_categoryIds = $ids;
        }
        return $this->_categoryIds;
    }


    public function getIdsString(){
        return implode(',', $this->getCategoryIds());
    }


    public function getRootNode(){
        $root = $this->getRoot();
        if ($root && in_array($root->getId(), $this->getCategoryIds())) {
            $root->setChecked(true);
        }
        return $root;
    }

    public function getRoot($parentNodeCategory = null, $recursionLevel = 3){
        if (!is_null($parentNodeCategory) && $parentNodeCategory->getId()) {
            return $this->getNode($parentNodeCategory, $recursionLevel);
        }
        $root = Mage::registry('category_root');
        if (is_null($root)) {
            $rootId = Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::TREE_ROOT_ID;
            $ids = $this->getSelectedCategotyPathIds($rootId);
            $tree = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/category_tree')
                ->loadByIds($ids, false, false);
            if ($this->getCategory()) {
                $tree->loadEnsuredNodes($this->getCategory(), $tree->getNodeById($rootId));
            }
            $tree->addCollectionData($this->getCategoryCollection());
            $root = $tree->getNodeById($rootId);
            Mage::register('category_root', $root);
        }
        return $root;
    }


    protected function _getNodeJson($node, $level = 1){
        $item = parent::_getNodeJson($node, $level);
        if ($this->_isParentSelectedCategory($node)) {
            $item['expanded'] = true;
        }
        if (in_array($node->getId(), $this->getCategoryIds())) {
            $item['checked'] = true;
        }
        return $item;
    }


    protected function _isParentSelectedCategory($node){
        $result = false;
        // Contains string with all category IDs of children (not exactly direct) of the node
        $allChildren = $node->getAllChildren();
        if ($allChildren) {
            $selectedCategoryIds = $this->getCategoryIds();
            $allChildrenArr = explode(',', $allChildren);
            for ($i = 0, $cnt = count($selectedCategoryIds); $i < $cnt; $i++) {
                $isSelf = $node->getId() == $selectedCategoryIds[$i];
                if (!$isSelf && in_array($selectedCategoryIds[$i], $allChildrenArr)) {
                    $result = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }


    protected function _getSelectedNodes(){
        if ($this->_selectedNodes === null) {
            $this->_selectedNodes = array();
            $root = $this->getRoot();
            foreach ($this->getCategoryIds() as $categoryId) {
                if ($root) {
                    $this->_selectedNodes[] = $root->getTree()->getNodeById($categoryId);
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->_selectedNodes;
    }

    public function getCategoryChildrenJson($categoryId){
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
        $node = $this->getRoot($category, 1)->getTree()->getNodeById($categoryId);
        if (!$node || !$node->hasChildren()) {
            return '[]';
        }
        $children = array();
        foreach ($node->getChildren() as $child) {
            $children[] = $this->_getNodeJson($child);
        }
        return Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($children);
    }

    public function getLoadTreeUrl($expanded = null){
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/categoriesJson', array('_current' => true));
    }

    public function getSelectedCategoryPathIds($rootId = false){
        $ids = array();
        $categoryIds = $this->getCategoryIds();
        if (empty($categoryIds)) {
            return array();
        }
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection');
        if ($rootId) {
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', $rootId);
        }
        else {
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$categoryIds));
        }

        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            if ($rootId && !in_array($rootId, $item->getPathIds())) {
                continue;
            }
            foreach ($item->getPathIds() as $id) {
                if (!in_array($id, $ids)) {
                    $ids[] = $id;
                }
            }
        }
        return $ids;
    }
}
```

here is controller file-

```
<?php

class Assel_Po_Adminhtml_PoproductController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    protected function _initAction() {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('Purchase')
            ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Purchase Order Product'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Purchase Order Product'));

        return $this;
    }

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->_initAction()
            ->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('po/adminhtml_poproduct'))
            ->renderLayout();
    }

    public function newAction() {
        $this->_forward('edit');
    }

    public function editAction() {
        $poid  = $this->getRequest()->getParam('po_product_id');
        $model  = Mage::getModel('po/poproduct')->load($poid);
        if ($model->getPoProductId() || $poid == 0) {
            $this->_initAction();
            $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData(true);
            if (!empty($data)) {
                $model->setData($data);
            }

            Mage::register('poproduct_data', $model);
            //$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);
            $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('po/adminhtml_poproduct_edit'));
                //->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('sharkslideshow/adminhtml_sharkrevslider_edit_tabs'));

            $this->renderLayout();
        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('po')->__('Purchase product does not exist'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }


    public function saveAction() 
    {
         if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost())
         {
             $model = Mage::getModel('po/poproduct');
             if ($id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('po_product_id')) {
                $model->load($id);
             } 

             $model_poproduct = Mage::getModel('po/poproduct');
             $model_poproduct->setData($data)->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('po_product_id'));

             /*save existing product with product_id */
             $product_id= $data['product_id'];

             $product_name= $data['product_name'];
             $product_expiry_date=$data['expiry_date'];
             $product_mrp=$data['mrp'];
             $product_rate=$data['rate'];
             $tax_rate=$data['tax'];
             $special_price=$data['special_price'];
             $product_qty=$data['qty'];
             if($product_id)
             {
                  try{ 
                         /* get all attributes of all products */
                         Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

                         $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($product_id);

                         $product->setName($product_name);
                         $product->setPrice($product_mrp);
                         $product->setExpiryDate($product_expiry_date);
                         $product->setSpecialPrice($special_price);
                         if($tax_rate==0){$product->setTaxClassId(1);}
                         elseif($tax_rate==5){$product->setTaxClassId(5);}
                         else{$product->setTaxClassId(6);}

                         $product_current_qty= (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();
                         $product->setStockData(array(
                                                       'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, 
                                                       'manage_stock'=>1, 
                                                       'min_sale_qty'=>1, 
                                                       'is_in_stock' => 1, 
                                                       'qty' => $product_current_qty+$product_qty
                                                  )
                                                );
                        $product->save();
                    }
                     catch(Exception $e){
                        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
                     }
             }
             else
             {
                 Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
                 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                 try
                 {
                     $product
                        ->setStoreId(1) //you can set data in store scope
                        ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
                        ->setAttributeSetId(9) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
                        ->setTypeId('simple') //product type
                        ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product creation time
                    //    ->setUpdatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product update time

                    //  ->setSku('testsku61') //SKU
                        ->setName($product_name) //product name
                    //  ->setWeight(4.0000)
                        ->setStatus(1) //product status (1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
                    //  ->setTaxClassId(4) //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
                        ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) //catalog and search visibility
                    //  ->setManufacturer(28) //manufacturer id
                    //  ->setColor(24)
                    //  ->setNewsFromDate('06/26/2014') //product set as new from
                    //  ->setNewsToDate('06/30/2014') //product set as new to
                    //  ->setCountryOfManufacture('AF') //country of manufacture (2-letter country code)

                        ->setPrice($product_mrp) //price in form 11.22
                    //  ->setCost(22.33) //price in form 11.22
                        ->setSpecialPrice($special_price) //special price in form 11.22
                    //  ->setSpecialFromDate('06/1/2014') //special price from (MM-DD-YYYY)
                    //  ->setSpecialToDate('06/30/2014') //special price to (MM-DD-YYYY)
                    //  ->setMsrpEnabled(1) //enable MAP
                    //  ->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(1) //display actual price (1 - on gesture, 2 - in cart, 3 - before order confirmation, 4 - use config)
                    //  ->setMsrp(99.99) //Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price

                    //  ->setMetaTitle('test meta title 2')
                    //  ->setMetaKeyword('test meta keyword 2')
                    //  ->setMetaDescription('test meta description 2')

                    //  ->setDescription('This is a long description')
                    //  ->setShortDescription('This is a short description')

                    //  ->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ())) //media gallery initialization
                    //  ->addImageToMediaGallery('media/catalog/product/1/0/10243-1.png', array('image','thumbnail','small_image'), false, false) //assigning image, thumb and small image to media gallery

                        ->setStockData(array(
                                           'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                                           'manage_stock'=>1, //manage stock
                                           'min_sale_qty'=>1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                                           'max_sale_qty'=>2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                                           'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                                           'qty' => $product_qty //qty
                                       )
                        );

                        if($tax_rate==0){$product->setTaxClassId(1);}
                        elseif($tax_rate==5){$product->setTaxClassId(5);}
                        else{$product->setTaxClassId(6);}

                    //  ->setCategoryIds(array(3, 10)); //assign product to categories
                    $product->save();
                 }
                 catch(Exception $e){
                        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
                 }

             }

             try {
                 $model_poproduct->save();

                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('po')->__('Product has been saved succesfully'));
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setFormData(false);
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) { /* true if save and continue edit button is clicked*/
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('po_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('po_id'),'po_product_id' => $model_poproduct->getPoProductId()));
                    return;
                }

                $this->_redirect('po/adminhtml_po/edit',array('po_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('po_id')));
                return;
             }
             catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setFormData($data);
                $this->_redirect('po/adminhtml_poproduct/edit',array('po_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('po_id')));
                return;
            }
         }
    }


    public function deleteAction() {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'adminhtml'));
        if(  Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn() )
        {
            $po_productId=$this->getRequest()->getParam('po_product_id');
            if( $po_productId > 0 ) {
                try {
                    $po_product = Mage::getModel('po/poproduct')->load($po_productId);
                    $po_product->setIsDeleted(1)->setId($po_productId)->save();

                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Product  was successfully deleted',$po_productId));
                    $this->_redirect('po/adminhtml_po/edit/po_id/'.$this->getRequest()->getParam('po_id').'/po_product_id/'.$po_productId);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                    $this->_redirect('po/adminhtml_po/edit/po_id/'.$this->getRequest()->getParam('po_id'));
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('You are not authorized to perform this action'));
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }


    public function massDeleteAction() {
        $poproductsIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('po_product_id');

        // only superadmin cam perform this action
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'adminhtml'));
        if(  Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn() )
        {
            if(!is_array($poproductsIds)) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Please select product(s)'));
            } else {
                try {
                    foreach ($poproductsIds as $poproductsId) {
                        $poProduct = Mage::getModel('po/poproduct')->load($poproductsId);
                        $poProduct->setIsDeleted(1)->setId($poproductsId)->save();
                    }
                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(
                        Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__(
                            'Total of %d Product(s) were successfully deleted', count($poproductsIds)
                        )
                    );
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {       
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('You are not authorized to perform this action'));
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
    }

    public function categoriesJsonAction(){
        $this->_initPoproduct();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('po/adminhtml_poproduct_edit_categories')
                ->getCategoryChildrenJson($this->getRequest()->getParam('category'))
        );
    }

    protected function _initPoproduct(){
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
        $poproductId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('po_product_id');
        $poproduct    = Mage::getModel('po/poproduct');

        if ($poproductId) {
            $poproduct->load($poproductId);
        }
        Mage::register('current_poproduct', $poproduct);
        return $poproduct;
     }
}
```

Please anyone help me to solve this.

hanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function getCategoriesArray() {

    $categoriesArray = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSort('path', 'asc')
            ->load()
            ->toArray();

    $categories = array();
    foreach ($categoriesArray as $categoryId => $category) {
        if (isset($category['name']) && isset($category['level'])) {
            $categories[] = array(
                'label' => $category['name'],
                'level'  =>$category['level'],
                'value' => $categoryId
            );
        }
    }

    return $categories;
}
```

to add in form

```
 $fieldset->addField('categories', 'multiselect', array(
            'label' => $this->__('Categories'),
            'name' => 'categories',
            'values' => $this->getCategoriesArray(),
        ));
```

Comment: In which file I need to put above function.?

Comment: put in your form.php

Comment: yes i did and i get all categories in multiselect field but I want to show categories as same as categories tree just like in edit product section in magento default. Hope you understand

Comment: for that you have to look this block 
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Categories and this phtml file 

catalog/product/edit/categories.phtml

Comment: Where do I put these, because I don't have  for it.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same Problem.
I was using the same solution you have linked and couldn't get the categories to show up.

Two things that were important:

1. Check your categories.phtml especially the Javascript part and be
   sure that all classes in the JS are correct.
2. At least in Magento 1.9 you have to be sure, that extJS is loaded. Use one of the following ways to use extJS:

a) In your controller use this:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);
```

b) In your layout xml use this:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setCanLoadExtJs">
        <value>1</value>
    </action>
</reference>
```