# Add Category Tree to mass update product functionality

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, category-tree, massaction

I need to add **Category** option to mass update product functionality as shown below

[image]

As these three are being added from `htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute/Tab/`, need some guidance about it.

Comment: check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88929/add-category-tree-structure-in-custom-module-form

Comment: check this if find it helpful  http://www.magebuzz.com/blog/how-to-add-category-tree-tab-to-custom-module/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add new tab to Catalog , Product Mass action page](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139778/add-new-tab-to-catalog-product-mass-action-page)