# 1.8 - Add category tree to CMS page tab

Tags: magento-1.8, category-tree

I have followed the guide [here](https://raivis.com/add-custom-product-category-and-cms-page-tabs-in-magento-admin/) and created a custom tab on CMS Pages:

[image]

I now want to add a Category tree to this custom page.  I have an answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14842) but I'm confused by this step:

In your form file where you add the tabs of your custom entity add this also:

```
$this->addTab('categories', array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('[module]')->__('Associated categories'),
    'url'   => $this->getUrl('*/*/categories', array('_current' => true)),
    'class'    => 'ajax'
));
```

I am not sure what is meant by "form file".  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Category tree in custom extension](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14833/add-category-tree-in-custom-extension)

Answer (score 0):

It should be **Tabs.php** (Tab file) in the custom extension

You can see the following core file of **catalog -> Manage product -> categories** tab in **admin pane**l

```
app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tabs.php
```

Here you can see the same code:

```
$this->addTab('categories', array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('[module]')->__('Categories'),
    'url'   => $this->getUrl('*/*/categories', array('_current' => true)),
    'class'    => 'ajax'
));
```

That's it.
Hope it help to you.